# Best way to optimize regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to optimize regex?
I have this regex:

```
/[A-Z](.*)?[a-z]|[a-z](.*)?[A-Z]/
```

I want to optimize this like:

```
/([A-Z])?([a-z])?(.*)?([a-z])?([A-Z])?/
```

I want to avoid `or`.

Thanx in advanced

Comment: Every character class is an implicit OR, and without alternations a regex is quite useless.

Comment: The second regex accepts anything. (?)

Comment: I don't see how avoiding OR would optimise anything. Your attempt sacrifices length, speed, readability, and correctness. What are you really looking for?

Comment: Yes, the requirement will help finding a better regex pattern. Please post the actual requirement

Comment: so just ignoring case will not work?

Comment: There is absolutely a way to optimize a regex but only if requirements are clear enough. What's wrong with `(?i)[a-z](.*)?[a-z]`?

Comment: `(.*)?` - silliness

Comment: This `( .* )? ` is weird. Optionally get everything? Since each alternation part contain opposite begin and end characters, there is nothing you can do. If you could do branch reset `(?![A-Z](.*)?[a-z]|[a-z](.*)?[A-Z])` then capture group 1 is the same. But you cant do that in JS. Just check which one matched if you can. Even in a callback (if replace) just test the truth `str.replace(/[A-Z](.*)?[a-z]|[a-z](.*)?[A-Z]/, function(match,p1,p2){ if ( p1 ) // it matched else p2 matched });`

Comment: Optional capturing of everything in between e.g. `ab`, `a-----b`, `abbbbbbbbc`, `ab----` why should be weird? @sln

Comment: @revo - Engines do first what's in parenthesis, then ask questions later. There is a Boolean esque to groupings. If `(...)` matched, it is defined. If a `?` (0 or 1) quantifier is added `(...)?` and it didn't match, it is marked  NULL or un-defined, but passes the overall match. There is an overhead to that logic. The group quantifier has no effect on it's contents, so if it's contents are `.*`,  this expression always matches. However, the group quantifier is always checked after the fact, and adds overhead. The result is that `(.*)` is equal to `(.*)?` with added overhead.

Comment: Maybe the *overhead* that you are talking about is OP's intention as if he needs output to have first numbered group or no grouping at all. @sln

Comment: @revo - Yeah but that's a different issue. Any groups that do not participate in the match (say in an alternation) never change from their default status, which is undefined/NULL. If it does participate `(.*)?` is a slower version of `(.*)` and they both match identical in all cases.

Comment: You do not need to get rid of the `|`, just use appropriate code around this regex.